# Laravel - display results from specific column (paginate)

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, pagination

Morning all,

I am seeking assistance enabling me to display weekly schedules in my league. The schedules I would like to be shown week by week identified in MySQL by column weekIndex.

As of now, I can display all the schedules on one blade. Hopefully below I have included enough detail.

**SchedulesController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Schedule;
use App\Models\Team;
use App\Models\League;
use App\Models\Player;
use App\Models\Standing;
use App\Models\Stat;

class SchedulesController extends Controller
{

function index(League $league, Team $teams, Schedule $schedules){
    $schedules = $league->schedule;
    $teams = $league->team;
    return view('schedules.index', compact('league','schedules', 'teams'));
}

function show($league, $schedule, Team $team){
    $schedule    = Schedule::where('leagueId', $league)->where('scheduleId', $schedule)->get();
    $league      = League::find($league);
    $team = $league->team;
    return view('schedules.show')->withSchedule($schedule)->withLeague($league)->withTeam($team);
}}
```

**Schedule Model**

```
namespace app\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Schedule extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'schedule';
    public $primaryKey = 'scheduleId';

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Profile');
    }
    public function league()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\League', 'leagueId');
    }
    public function player()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Player', 'leagueId');
    }
    public function team()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Team', 'leagueId');
    }
    public function stat()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Stat', 'statId');
    }
    }
```

**Schedule index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($schedules as $schedule)
<tr>
   <td class="team-schedule__away"><a href=""><img src="/images/teams/64/{{$schedule->awayTeamId}}.png"></a></td>
   <td class="team-schedule__awayscore">{{$schedule->awayScore}}</td>
   <td class="team-schedule__at"><img src="/images/at.png"alt="at" width="50px"></td>
   <td class="team-schedule__homescore">{{$schedule->homeScore}}</td>
   <td class="team-schedule__home"><a href=""><img src="/images/teams/64/{{$schedule->homeTeamId}}.png"></a></td>
   <td class="team-schedule__tickets"><a href="./result/{{$schedule->scheduleId}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-default-alt btn-block ">Preview</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@else
<p>
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button> <strong>Schedules Not Found!</strong> Please try to sync your league following the included instructions HERE</div>
</div>
@endif
</tbody>
```

I have included an image below showing the debugbar and it displaying all 333 schedules. Each schedule belongs to a weekIndex in MySQL (0-22 weeks)

[image: Image of index.blade.php & debugbar]

[image: Schedule MySQL]

**League Model**

```
namespace app\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class League extends Model


    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'leagues';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The attributes that are not mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that are hidden.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    /**
     * Fillable fields for a Profile.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'shortName',
        'exportId',
        'platform',
        'taggable_id',
        'taggable_type',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id'            => 'integer',
        'name'          => 'string',
        'shortName'     => 'string',
        'exportId'      => 'string',
        'platform'      => 'string',
        'taggable_id'   => 'integer',
        'taggable_type' => 'string',
    ];

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function rules($id = 0, $merge = [])
    {
        return array_merge(
            [
                'name'      => 'required|min:3|max:50|unique:leagues,name'.($id ? ",$id" : ''),
                'shortName' => 'required|min:3|max:10|unique:leagues,shortName'.($id ? ",$id" : ''),
                'exportId'  => 'max:5',
                'platform'  => 'required',
            ],
            $merge
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the profiles for the league.
     */
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Profile');
    }
    public function team()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Team', 'leagueId');
    }

    public function player()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Player', 'leagueId');
    }

    public function schedule()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Schedule', 'leagueId');
    }

    public function stat()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Stat', 'leagueId');
    }}
```

[image: edd($schedules)]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only schedules for current week, you can use Carbon in your query, like this:

`$schedules = $league->schedule->where('weekIndex', Carbon::now()->week())`

EDIT: If you want them grouped, just use groupBy, like this:

`$schedules = $league->schedule->groupBy('weekIndex');`

I think that's what you're looking for

Comment: Hi, thanks for the swift response but neither work. The Carbon returns a blank page, and the second suggestion states that the property doesnt exist in the collection

Comment: I have included an image of my table in MySQL. I would like all weekIndex = 0 schedules to be displayed on a single page, weekIndex = 1 displayed on a second page and so on up until weekIndex = 22

Comment: I have tried ```$schedules = Schedule::where('weekIndex', $schedules)->paginate();``` to no gain. This results in 15 schedules being brought into the blade.

Comment: How does your League model look? How is the schedule relation created? That's wierd that the `weekIndex` doesnt exist. Can you group by any other column, eg. `$schedules = $league->schedule->groupBy('awayTeamId');`?

Comment: I have added my League Model to the original post for your perusal. When I groupBy ```awayTeamId``` I get the same error stating that the property doesn't exist in the collection

Comment: Can you paste what `dd($schedules)` shows in index method? Just paste it before return statement. Also, I don't think you need `Team $teams, Schedule $schedules` in your index method parameters, since it looks like you're only passing `$league` parameter

Comment: Added the DD for you

Comment: Your $schedules is instance of Schedule model instead of collection of schedules related to league. Please delete `Team $teams, Schedule $schedules` from index method parameters.

Your route should look like this `/league/{{league}}/schedules` and only {{league}} should be bind in index method.

Also, the convention is to name your hasMany relationship as plural, eg. `public function schedules()`

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I have deleted ```Team $teams, Schedule $schedules``` from the index. My route already is as you state, if I change the hasMany relationship to plural it shows "call to a member function groupBy on NULL". When I dd $schedule it shows now undefined module.

Comment: Aren't you missing an opening `{` in your League model class? This may be the reason your relationship is not loading.

Anyway, i would strongly recommend following [naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions). This saves much time, since you don't have to define things like `$table` and `$primaryKey` and  allows Laravel to automatically do many cool things for you, eg. in defining relationship you only need to select relationship class, and do not need to provide foreign key. It also makes your code easier to read